# Resize the width and height of the ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

How do I set a chart's width and  height using ng2-charts? I'm making a Bar chart, just like the demo on the ng2-charts site.

```
public doughnutChartLabels:string[] = ['EMI', 'Car', 'Food', 'Fuel'];
data:number[] = [3350, 5450, 4100, 1000];
  public doughnutChartType:string = 'doughnut';
  options: { responsive: true, }
  colorsEmptyObject: Array<Color> = [{}];
  public datasets: any[] = [
  {
    data: this.data,
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ]
  }];
  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For rectangular shaped graphs (line, bar) you can include a `width` and `height` tag in the html:

```
<canvas baseChart width="2" height="1"
        [datasets]="chartData"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [options]="chartOptions"
        [colors]="chartColors"
        [legend]=true
        chartType=line></canvas>
```

The width and height set the aspect ratio, not the actual size.

You *can* do this for square shaped graphs (donut, radar, pie, polar), but it doesn't make as much sense. It will keep a square shape, but with bigger padding on the sides or top and bottom.

Instead, you can set the exact size you want on a `div` containing the chart:

```
<div style="display: block; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <canvas baseChart
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
</div>
```